# How to apply Tailwind CSS breakpoints in style object in JSX / React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I have a `<div>` tag in my React component and I want to apply `style` to it. The problem is I'm not sure how to apply or whether it is possible or not to apply Tailwind CSS screen-size breakpoints here. Consider following example, here in the width property in style object, I want to conditionally apply width based on Tailwind CSS breakpoints e.g. `sm`, `md` etc.

```js
const styles = {
  backgroundColor: '#885748',
  height: '56px',
  width: '48px'  //or 56px for another screen-size md ??????
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  return(
    <div style={styles}>
      sample content
    </div>
  )
}
```

I believe same thing can be achieved by calculating screen size in JS and compare it with a specific value. But since whole the app is using Tailwind CSS, using the same breakpoints is desirable. Can you assist me solving this problem? Kindly comment if I missed something or additional info required.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMediaQuery` hook from any library e.g. https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-media-query to create your own hook for specific values:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const breakpoint = useBreakpoint();
  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: "#885748",
    height: "56px",
    width: (() => {
      switch (breakpoint) {
        case "sm":
          return "48px";
        default:
          "100px";
      }
    })(),
  };

  return <div style={styles}>sample content</div>;
};

const useBreakpoint = () => {
  const queries = {
    sm: useMediaQuery("(min-width: 640px)"),
    md: useMediaQuery("(min-width: 768px)"),
    lg: useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1024px)"),
    xl: useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1280px)"),
    "2xl": useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1536px)"),
  };

  return Object.entries(queries).find(([, val]) => val)[0];
};
```